# why checking equality between three strings not works but between three numbers does?

Tags: javascript, compare, equality

I have checked equality between three numbers in javascript and it works. like:

```
1 == 1 == 1 //true
2 == 3 == 4 //false
2 == 3 == 3 //false
```

But when I try this check between three strings, it does not work:

```
'some string' == 'some string' == 'some string' //false
'a' == 'a' == 'a' //false
```

Does anyone know why this happens?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this: `1 == 1 == 1` -> `1 == true` -> `1 == 1` -> `true`

Comment: (x == x) is `true` or `false` ... so the third thing better be truthy or falsey

Comment: Also, never ever use `==` in javascript!

Comment: @georg - except when appropriate

Comment: @Bravo: which is, never ;)

Comment: @georg - if it were never, then the syntax wouldn't exist

Comment: @georg `==` is pretty useful. I don't really get why some people don't like it. (If you want to use a typed system e.g. typescript, you'd still not have problem either way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
'some string' == 'some string' == 'some string'
```

evaluates the `==` operators in left-to-right order. It's equivalent to

```
('some string' == 'some string') == 'some string'
```

which is

```
true == 'some string'
```

which is false, because when a boolean is compared against something else, according to the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.

When the right-hand side is a string, this resolves to

```
1 == 'some string'
```

which then runs

> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).

but `ToNumber('some string')` is `NaN`

```js
console.log(Number('some string'));
```

so the comparison evaluates to `false`.

On the other hand, with `1 == 1 == 1`, following the same process:

```
1 == 1 == 1
(1 == 1) == 1
true == 1
// Rule 8, turn left side into a number:
1 == 1
true
```

Conclusion: Always use `===`. If you use `==`, you will encounter strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

1 == 1 == 1 can be interpreted as (1 == 1 (true) == 1) which is true.
But 'a' == 'a' == 'a' would be interpreted as ('a' == 'a' (true) == 'a') which would be false. as true is not equal to 'a'.